# What is the difference between wait_timeout and interactive_timeout?

Tags: mysql

What is actual difference between `wait_timeout` and `interactive_timeout`?

Answer (score 48):

`interactive_time` is for interactive sessions, whereas `wait_timeout` is for non-interactive sessions.

What's an interactive session?  It's one with a human at the keyboard.

When your code connects to MySQL, runs a query and then spends 3 seconds processing that query before disconnecting, that's 3 seconds of the `wait_timeout`.

When you use the `mysql` command line client to connect, run a command and spend 10 seconds reading the output, that's 10 seconds of `interactive_timeout`.  If you walk away and have lunch, that's 3600 seconds of `interactive_timeout`.

In both cases, when you or your code runs another query, the waiting time is reset back to 0.

You can see the values for all the current sessions by typing `show processlist`.  The values in the `sleep(5)` function is the number of seconds since that connection last did anything.

Comment: thank you, this helped me a lot to understand the difference, very well explained.

Comment: so let's say I have a query that takes 2 minutes to run, would MySQL disconnect my connections if wait_timeout is less than 2 minutes?