# Getting broken pipe error after spending significant time idle in mysql command line

Tags: ssh, mysql

I often spend a lot of time in my `MySQL` console - managing databases, making sure the integrity is in tact and browsing through recent records for possible vulnerabilities.

Whenever I am active with SSH on my servers, it lasts up to 1 hour, but whenever I am in a `MySQL` terminal, it closes with `broken pipe` within 20 minutes of inactivity or less. This is not practical for me as I am often shuffling between different terminals with open `SSH` to like 5 different servers, code editors and what have you. It gets quite frustrating to have to re-connect to the server and run all the user commands and the `MySQL` commands and passwords every 20 minutes.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between wait\_timeout and interactive\_timeout?](https://serverfault.com/questions/375136/what-is-the-difference-between-wait-timeout-and-interactive-timeout) Moreover you did not show any research you done nor which manual you read. take note about to care of [ask]